# use Simple Editor from Rich Text Editor for ASP.NET and MVC 8.0.1

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

how to use Simple Editor from  Rich Text Editor for ASP.NET and MVC 8.0.1 ?

I'm using the code below :

```
  public ActionResult Index()
        {
            Editor Editor1 = new Editor(System.Web.HttpContext.Current, "Editor1");
            Editor1.LoadFormData("Content");
            Editor1.MvcInit();
            ViewBag.Editor = Editor1.MvcGetString();
            return View();
        }
```

How do I use the simple mode?

simple mode : http://richtexteditor.com/demo/simple_editor.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's all there in the documentation.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    Editor Editor1 = new Editor(System.Web.HttpContext.Current, "Editor1");
    Editor1.LoadFormData("Content");
    Editor1.MvcInit();
    Editor1.RenderMode = RTERenderMode.Simple;
    ViewBag.Editor = Editor1.MvcGetString();
    return View();
}
```

Relevant documentation:

1. [RenderMode property](http://richtexteditor.com/document/scr/html/68c590a6-5fd4-0b25-2297-4604d38ad2bb.htm)
2. [RTERenderMode enumeration](http://richtexteditor.com/document/scr/html/18cb5f6e-cd29-7831-59a2-e4502b6e6ca8.htm)

Answer (score 0):

i found :

```
Editor1.Toolbar = "minimal";
```